# Insert Convert google product taxonomy inside a dropdown

Tags: php

I try to convert a google product taxonomy inside a dropdown but I am blocked on the the loop
Also this line must not appear.

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/basepages/producttype/taxonomy-with-ids.en-US.txt');
$file = explode("\n", $file);

var_dump($fields);
```

example of `$fields`:

```
array(0) { } array(1) { [0]=> string(45) "# Google_Product_Taxonomy_Version: 2019-07-10" } array(1) { [0]=> string(26) "1 - Animals & Pet Supplies" } array(2) { [0]=> string(29) "3237 - Animals & Pet Supplies" [1]=> string(12) "Live Animals" } array(2) { [0]=> string(26) "2 - Animals & Pet Supplies" [1]=> string(12) "Pet Supplies" }
```

How to finish that ?
Thank you.

Comment: Convert to ...? And what is the problem with your loop (where is your code and problem description)? And what do you mean by "this line must not appear"?!

Comment: Your variable is called $files but you are dumping $fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if i have understood your question correctly, you need to make a dropdown list from that file and cant create a loop. I dont know what

> Also this line must not appear.

means but feel free correct me when following answer doesnt satisfy your needs.

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/basepages/producttype/taxonomy-with-ids.en-US.txt');
$file = explode("\n", $file);
?>
<select name="dropdown" class="dropdown">
<option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
<?php
foreach($file as $key =>$value)
{
  ?>
<option value="<?=$value?>"><?=$value?></option>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: what he meant was to create a multilevel nested dropdown